# HP TSB program stored format

Tags: basic, file-format, hp

The internal representation for a HP TSB Access program is detailed in the 'Sources and Listings' Documentation ref 22687-90020. This describes (pages 5-28 & 5-29) how string variables, simple variables etc are encoded in the program.

However this internal representation for variables changes if the program is saved using 'CSAVE' (semi-compiled save) rather than the normal 'SAVE'.

I have a C++ program which extracts from the contributed library dump tape file (2000dmp5-5-84iclContrib.tape) Access Basic programs in the original text format when they are stored in the 'SAVE' format. I'd like to do the same with those saved in the 'CSAVE' format.

Can anyone shed any light on to the internal representation used for 'CSAVE' format or point me to any documentation which describes this please.

Comment: I have now re-saved the CSAVEd programs with SAVE to get them in the SAVE format (there were only 175) (from within the simh hp tsb software kit). I've created a new DUMP tape file that contains all the contributed library files and programs in SAVE format. From that tape file I've extracted all the Basic programs as txt files. I have a zip file of these (3.43Mb) and a zip of the TAPE file (3.23Mb). If any one wants a copy of these zip files or wishes to host them, please let me know.

Comment: If these aren't already on the internet archive, I'd be glad to help put them there

Comment: they are uploaded : [HP 2000 TSB Access Contributed Library : HP : Free Download, Borrow, and Streaming : Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/tsb_contrib)